# Elixir phoenix set websocket response headers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do I set Sec-WebSocket-Protocol to the response header in phoenix websocket?

I have tried Plugs to add the header field to the `conn` object but it seems like somewhere along the way it has been dropped.
The other option I tried was to create a custom websocket by importing `Phoenix.Transport.Websocket` but ended up with no success.

Comment: This is exactly the same thing i am trying to do!!!! Did you end up finding an answer?

Comment: Sorry @Acidic, I did not find an answer yet, my plan is to dig into the socket layer and find out what's going on.

Comment: https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe/issues/661#event-2049601020 I made a github issue and using the link he provided I managed to get it to work. Not sure if its the same issue as yours though but that has solved it for me in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Acidic, I ll check this out and let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

Support for this is under way in phoenix, see pull request [#3444](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/3444). If you really need to try it out, consider cherry-picking the patch on top of your fork of phoenix, or using phoenix from PR author's branch directly.

The header will be set [automatically](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/3444/files#diff-f45e845b5215b7a74cea6cad7061e47bR378) if it was passed by client. Per added docs:

> If the sec-websocket-protocol header matches the allowed subprotocol, it will put sec-websocket-protocol response header and return the given connection.
>
> If no sec-websocket-protocol header was sent it will return the given connection.

Comment: Thank you @gmaile for the information, will try it out soon